# Bad Pointer in Structure variable initialization

Tags: pointers, structure

I have got a structure that I am trying to initialize with some addresses.
I get run time error of bad pointers. Basically addresses are not stored correctly.

```
typedef struct    
{

   Uint8      *pInAddr[2];         

}structtest2_t;  


typedef struct    
{              

   structtest2_t  structtest2[2]; 

}structtest_t;

structtest_t  structtest;
```

I try to initialize as follows:

```
structtest.structtest2[0].pInAddr[0]=(uint8*)(someaddress);
```

I dont get compilation error but there is bad pointer when i see the value.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Maybe someaddress is bad or not used correctly. Or maybe your program inadvertently accesses the uninitialized structtext.structtest2[1].

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change:

```
structtest.structtest2[0]=(uint8*)(someaddress);
```

to:

```
structtest.structtest2[0].pInAddr[0]=(uint8*)(someaddress);
```

I'm surprised that you don't get a compiler warning for your code - are you using `gcc -Wall` or equivalent ?

Comment: Hi, It was a typing error on my part. Actual code has the same form as u have suggested. I get wrong address strored and it gives bad pointer  message in watch window. I am using MSVC compiler.Please help

Comment: @user437777: you need to copy and paste the actual code rather than typing in an approximation. What value is `someaddress` and what value do you see in `structtest.structtest2[0].pInAddr[0]` ?